# How to prevent infinite loop in componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I've got this code but it gives me an infinite loop.
How can I prevent it?

Or I need to use another lifecycle method??

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevState.input["purpose"] === "TEST" ){
            this.setState({input: { ...this.state.input, number: "1"}})
        }else if(prevState.input["purpose"] !== "TEST"){
            this.setState({input: { ...this.state.input, number: "0"}});
        }
        console.log(this.state.input.number);
        console.log(prevState.input["purpose"]);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases of `if-else`, you are updating the state and you are checking for the purpose to be 'Test'
if its 'Test' you are updating the state and if it's not still you are updating state

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the state in componentDidUpdate. Therefore, this function is called every time.
Both of your conditions call setState.

Comment: you must write conditions so that only under one condition it is called

Comment: I've tried only one condition it is still giving me a loop.

if(prevState.input["purpose"] === "TEST" ){
            this.setState({input: { ...this.state.input, number: "1"}})
        }

not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: can you tell in more detail what you want to get?

Comment: So initially my number 0, I just want to make it 1 whenever the purpose has been choosen TEST, if it is not TEST, set it back to 0

Comment: how you choose purpose?

Comment: with another function from dropdown select

Comment: you must change the number in the same place as the purpose

Comment: cause if you write this condition if(prevState.input["purpose"] === "TEST" )
you shoul change purpose too, but it's not the solution

Comment: just change it in onSelect handler

Comment: I do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101278/delay-updating-state-using-setstate?noredirect=1#comment115093632_65101278 and it causing delay, that's why I wanted to use componentDidUpdate

Comment: If you have a look it there, I am adding console log as a callback function, but I need to get rid of console.log

Comment: cause you did this.setState({input});  and after it you did if(this.state.input.myState === "TEXT"){
setState works acyncronously, you can't get state after setState.
you can just change your condition to if(input.myState === "TEXT")

Answer (score 0):

Following docs from React.js. You should not update state like `this.setState` inside componentDidUpdate without condition

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the component performance. If you’re trying to “mirror” some state to a prop coming from above, consider using the prop directly instead. Read more about why copying props into state causes bugs.

**In this case, your if else condition always update state**

Please, follow react component lifecycle as below

[image]